# FileNotFoundException with ObjectMapper in JSON/REST

Tags: java, json, rest

I have created a class that provides a method to obtain via REST a JSON object that should be then deserialised as LinkedHashMap. The method is the following:

```
 @Override
public LinkedHashMap refreshStatus(String metricType, String metricPeriod) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> map = null;

     try {
        map = mapper.readValue(new File("http://localhost:8081/Metrics/Stats/JSONP/ReceiveData/"+metricType+"/"+metricPeriod+"/?callback="), LinkedHashMap.class);


    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return map;
}
```

When I enter in the browser the URL with some specific parameters, i.e.

```
http://localhost:8081/Metrics/Stats/JSONP/ReceiveData/Totals/All/?callback=
```

I get a proper JSON object:

```
{"Boxes":"8","Contracts":"23","Updates":"1","Deactivations":"4","ActiveBoxes":"33","InactiveBoxes":"1","PendingInstallationsContracts":"70","Alerts":"626","PercentsBoxInstalled":"100.0%","Miles":"0"}
```

However when I run the application and the method is invoked, I get a FileNotFoudException:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/localhost:8081/Metrics/Stats/JSONP/ReceiveData/Totals/All/?callback= (No such file or directory)
```

Does anyone know where the problem may be? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This file indeed cannot be found on your computer. You try to create file objects correspoding to real file in your *local* file system and provide URL as an argument instead of file system path.

You actually want to perform HTTP GET, i.e. do something like the following.

```
urlString = "http://localhost:8081/Metrics/Stats/JSONP/ReceiveData/Totals/All/?callback=";
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
map = mapper.readValueconn.getInputStream();
```